# in RESTful API, which is better approach for DELETE/PUT/PATCH for uncachable user calls?

Tags: javascript, laravel, rest

For example I have the following route for `DELETE` method:

```
DELETE /api/user/{user_id}/friends/{friend_id}
```

this is a POST method so it won't be cached in the end because `user_id` is the logged in user **session** and can be obtained in the server

I can change the route to be (Which still uses parameter)

```
DELETE /api/user/friends/{friend_id}
```

or to be

```
DELETE /api/user/friends/
```

while sending the friend_id in the post request of axios

```
axios.delete(`/api/user/friends/`, { friend_id })
```

I have similar cases with PUT/PATCH too, so I was wondering what is the best approach for user-based API calls that won't be cached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
axios.delete(`/api/user/friends/`, { friend_id })
```

Expecting useful things to happen with a request body in a DELETE request is a Bad Idea [tm]

> content received in a DELETE request has no generally defined semantics -- [RFC 9110](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9110#section-9.3.5)

What this request is actually telling general purpose http components is that you are trying to DELETE the `/api/user/friends/` resource.  That's probably not what you want.

---

In general, the target URI for a DELETE (or a PUT or a PATCH) should use the same target URI as the GET request that fetches the current representation of the resource.

The motivation here is the uniform interface constraint of REST - we want HTTP messages to all mean the same thing, without regard to the specialization of the client or the resources on the server.

So GET always means "get the target", and put always means "update the target", and patch always means "patch the target" and delete always means "remove the association between the target resource and its current functionality".

Answer (score 1):

Route Design: If the friend relationship is directly related to the logged in user, it is good practice to include the user ID as part of the URL. In this way, you maintain structure

```
DELETE /api/user/{user_id}/friends/{friend_id}
```

Cache Control: To prevent caching of user-specific data, you can use appropriate HTTP headers to control caching behavior. For example

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```